# Inherit a common base class in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef4-code-only

I'm converting my EF POCO project to Code first. I had changed the T4 template, so that all my entities use a base class, `EntityBase`, that provides them with some common functionality that is not persistence related.

If I use `[NotMapped]` attribute on `EntityBase`, all entities inherit this attribute and I get a `The type 'X.X.Person' was not mapped`, for any type I try to use with EF.

If I use `[NotMapped]` on all properties of `EntityBase`, I get a `EntityType 'EntityBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType` exception

FYI: I use Ef 4.3.1

Edit: part of the code:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public abstract class EntityBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual int? Key
    {
        get { return GetKeyExtractor(ConversionHelper.GetEntityType(this))(this); }
    }
    //other properties and methods!
}
```

and then

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true), Table("Person", Schema = "PER")]
public abstract partial class Person : BaseClasses.EntityBase, ISelfInitializer
{
    #region Primitive Properties
    private int? _personID;
    [DataMember,Key]
    public virtual int? PersonID
    {
        get{ return _personID; }
        set{ SetPropertyValue<int?>(ref _personID, value, "PersonID"); }
    }
}
```

For these two classes there is not fluent api configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Try to define `EntityBase` as `abstract`, if it's possible for you, and put `NotMapped`... on the properties you don't want to map should do the trick.

Comment: @Alireza well, you speak of CodeFirst and T4 template. Is this really CodeFirst ? Can you show where and how you do the relationship mapping ? Cause we do use a base abstract class in CodeFirst, and it's working fine...

Comment: I used EF database first and POCO. At that time I'd changed T4 so that all my classes inherit `EntityBase`. Now that we switched to code first, the T4 no longer exists.

Comment: @Alireza Ok. Could you please try to show us : the EntityBase class, an example of inheriting class, and the corresponding part of the context configuration ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to create a table of EntityBase (Great blog post about this : [Table Per Type Inheritence](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)) that all your entities share, or to simply create a base object so all your entities can use the same methods?   I didn't have any problem with the code you posted above.  Here's the entirety of an quick test app:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual int? Key
    {
        get { return 1; } //GetKeyExtractor(ConversionHelper.GetEntityType(this))(this); }
    }
    //  other properties and methods!
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Person : EntityBase
{
    private int? _personID;
    [DataMember, Key]
    public virtual int? PersonID
    {
        get { return _personID; }
        set { _personID = value; }
    }
}

public class CFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Employers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(p.Key);
    }
}
```

Which created this table/database:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want to create just a base class. No inheritance from `EntityBase` happens in Database level. Unfortunately, the complete code is too large to upload somewhere. I should try and find a reason why this does not work in my code.